# Python3x Unbound Local Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have reviewed the answers to similar questions and have tried various recommended iterations but am not having any luck. I am getting this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rundate1' referenced before assignment" on the line "return pick.CalendarFrame(rundate1)". My code is

```
def GetCalendar():
os.system("Pick.py")

def rundate1():
    result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")
#result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno()
    if result == True:
        rundate1 = date.today() - timedelta(7)
        print("rundate 1 = ", rundate1)
        return rundate1

    else:
        GetCalendar()
        return pick.CalendarFrame(rundate1)
        print("rundate 1 = ", rundate1)
        return rundate1 

rundate = rundate1()
print("rundate = ", rundate)
```

The first part of the if statement works fine, I click yes and get the return data. When "no" is clicked my calendar dialog pops up and I can pick my dates but then it all falls apart. The app "Pick.py" works great on it's own. The submit for the CalendarFrame is

```
    def submit(): 
        start = self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        end = self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") 
        rundate1 = start, end
        return rundate1
        print(rundate1)
```

Help would be very nuch appreciated

Comment: You’re using the name `rundate1` both for a function and for a local date variable. I believe that if you changed one of them you would solve your problem (and possibly make the intention of your code more obvious too).

Comment: I think I must be misunderstanding. I kept the def rundate1() and changed the references to rundate1 within that def to rundate. (same with submit) I now get a pyodbc.programmingError: (invalid parameter type = function) in my execute "cur.execute(query, (rundate))

Comment: As @bdesham mentions, you shouldn't uses the same name, also on the else clause, you are using the `rundate1` variable, which is never initialized

Comment: I guess I am just slow. I completely do not understand. Is there someplace else I can go for help with this and my other question?